# Vanilla Javascript API call to randommer.io

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript and I am trying to make an API call to randommer.io using Vanilla Javascript, but it not working. I have read the documentation on Randommer but nothing same to work. I keep getting the Cross-Origin Request Blocked error. Any help how to solve this problem. Below is the code I am using to make the API call and and X-Api-Key is also valid.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
getData()
})



const getData = async function() {
    const result = await fetch(`https://randommer.io/api/Phone/Countries`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": '*',
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'x-Api-Key': 'xxxxxx',
        }
    })
    const data = await result.json()
    console.log(data)
}
```

Comment: The Server must allow the cors request. https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: It looks like their server does not allow cors so you might want to look into creating your own server-side wrapper for their API

Comment: I would recommend utilizing a server side language like PHP/Python etc..

Comment: According to their website when you scroll down to Frequently asked questions, it said that it allow CORS from any website and even from a simple HTML page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the cors-anywhere proxy which you could also setup yourself.

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
getData()
})



const getData = async function() {
    const result = await fetch(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://randommer.io/api/Phone/Countries`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": '*',
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'x-Api-Key': 'XXXX',
        }
    })
    const data = await result.json()
    console.log(data)
}
```

https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere

This is happening because you really should be running this server side via something like Node.js since they don't allow cors but this is a workaround if you want to run it like you are.

Comment: @William you leaked your API key, please change your API key right away.

Comment: Also glad I could help =]

Comment: I just reset it.

Comment: @William awesome just wanted to give ya a heads up incase you didnt notice =]

Answer (score 0):

Your server must accept cors, otherwise this call will not work.
What you can do is create a proxy as suggested to bypass its restriction.